# Metric on the Set of Binary rectangular matrices

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces

Consider a set of all possible Binary rectangular matrices.

How many non-equivalent metrics can be defined? How to define non equivalent metrics on this set precisely?

Comment: The coefficients of your matrix are in $\Bbb K=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ hence there in $\Bbb K^{n\times m}$ there is $\min(n,m)+1$ matrix.

Comment: Could you be little more clear?

Comment: Two matrices $A,B$ are not equivalent iff $\text{rank}(A)\neq \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: By *metric* do you mean a distance function that gives this (finite??) set a metric topology?  Did you mean to create a topology on *all* sizes of binary matrices taken together?

Comment: Yes, I mean distance function by saying Metric. I want all possible non equivalent metrics on the set of matrices as mentioned.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan: Important clarification -- *all* binary matrices of *all* sizes, or just binary matrices of fixed size $m\times n$ ?

Comment: All binary matrices of size fixed size m times n.

Comment: Closely related, but arguably not quite a duplicate: [Is it true that any metric on a finite set is the discrete metric?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461560/is-it-true-that-any-metric-on-a-finite-set-is-the-discrete-metric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the space consists of binary $m\times n$ matrices for fixed integers $m,n \gt 0$, then the number of such matrices is finite.  Any finite metric space has a discrete topology, so there is only one metric topology up to [topological equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).

Indeed [strong equivalence of metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) must also hold in this finite setting. Let $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ be two metrics on a finite set $S$.  Let $e_1,e_2$ be the minimum distances $d_1(x,y)$, resp. $d_2(x,y)$, over all distinct $x,y \in S$.  Similarly let $f_1,f_2$ be the maximum distances $d_1(x,y)$, resp. $d_2(x,y)$, over all distinct $x,y \in S$.  Then for any distinct $x,y \in S$:

$$ d_1(x,y) \lt (f_1 + 1) = e_2^{-1} (f_1 + 1) e_2 \le e_2^{-1} (f_1 + 1) d_2(x,y) $$

and by a similar estimate, $d_2(x,y) \lt e_1^{-1} (f_2 + 1) d_1(x,y)$.  Thus the two metrics are strongly equivalent.

Comment: @ Hardmath, any reference? Can you precisely mention a metric? I can think about Hamming metric (number of mismatches matrix entriwise). How does this metric unique then in terms of strong equivalence of metrics?

Comment: The reason I asked for a number of clarifications about your Question was to make sure the terms you were using ("metrics") were well-defined.  You agree that by metric was meant a [distance function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)).  There is a widely adopted notion of *equivalence of metrics* which says two metrics are equivalent iff the topologies they give are the same (see link in Answer).

Comment: By *strong equivalence of metrics* is meant that for two distance functions $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ there exist positive constants $c_1,c_2$ such that for all $x\neq y$:  $$ d_1(x,y) \lt c_1 d_2(x,y)\; \text{ and } \; d_2(x,y) \lt c_2 d_1(x,y) $$

Comment: Thanks. So as I understood, there is unique non-equivalent metric on the set.

Comment: Yes, and this depends only on the set being finite, not the particular set being binary matrices of a fixed size.