# $\{2\}$ is both open and closed in $\{1,2,3\}$, equipped with the Euclidean metric

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $\{2\}$ is both open and closed in $\{1,2,3\}$, equipped with the Euclidean metric. Is the following correct?

Openness: $B_{0.5}(2)\subset\{2\}$. Hence, $\{2\}$ is open in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Closedness: $\{2\}$ trivially contains all its limit points, since it has no limit points. Hence, $\{2\}$ is closed in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you could argue that [on a finite set, any metric induces the discrete topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/461563/386889).

Comment: If I was your grader, I might ask you to prove that $\{2\}$ has no limit points. Though it'd be easy to do based on what you've already written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct, and the answer is OK *so long as you have already proven that $\{2\}$ has no limit points*. This is simple to prove, of course, but it still should be done.

Alternatively, you could also say that because $\{1\}$ is also open (by the same argument as $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ is also open, then the complement of $\{2\}$, which is $\{1,3\}=\{1\}\cup\{3\}$, is open, which means $\{2\}$ is closed.